# Android : Error on MoveToNext()

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I'm trying to use SQLite database on Android to stock an object Discuss (ID, USER) on a table which is (ID, ID2, USER).

I have set my database, and put some items (5) on it. I checked with an ADB SHELL and SQLITE3 command.

When I want to get all items with the following method :

```
public ArrayList<Discuss> getAllDiscuss(){
    ArrayList<Discuss> discussList = new ArrayList<Discuss>();
    Cursor cursor = bdd.query(TABLE_DISCUSS, new String[] {COL_DISCUSS_ID, COL_DISCUSS_ID_SERVER, COL_ID_OTHERUSER}, null, null, null, null, null);
    try {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                discussList.add(cursorToDiscuss(cursor));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    } finally {
        try { cursor.close(); } catch (Exception ignore) {}
    }
    return discussList;
}
```

I have this error :

```
02-04 23:48:25.333: E/AndroidRuntime(2122): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-04 23:48:25.333: E/AndroidRuntime(2122): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gam/com.gam.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery (mSql = SELECT ID, Id_Server, Id_OtherUser FROM Table_Discuss) 
02-04 23:48:25.333: E/AndroidRuntime(2122):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
02-04 23:48:25.333: E/AndroidRuntime(2122):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
02-04 23:48:25.333: E/AndroidRuntime(2122):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
02-04 23:48:25.333: E/AndroidRuntime(2122):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
02-04 23:48:25.333: E/AndroidRuntime(2122):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-04 23:48:25.333: E/AndroidRuntime(2122):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-04 23:48:25.333: E/AndroidRuntime(2122):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
02-04 23:48:25.333: E/AndroidRuntime(2122):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-04 23:48:25.333: E/AndroidRuntime(2122):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-04 23:48:25.333: E/AndroidRuntime(2122):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-04 23:48:25.333: E/AndroidRuntime(2122):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-04 23:48:25.333: E/AndroidRuntime(2122):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-04 23:48:25.333: E/AndroidRuntime(2122): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery (mSql = SELECT ID, Id_Server, Id_OtherUser FROM Table_Discuss) 
02-04 23:48:25.333: E/AndroidRuntime(2122):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:33)
02-04 23:48:25.333: E/AndroidRuntime(2122):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:82)
02-04 23:48:25.333: E/AndroidRuntime(2122):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:160)
02-04 23:48:25.333: E/AndroidRuntime(2122):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.onMove(SQLiteCursor.java:143)
02-04 23:48:25.333: E/AndroidRuntime(2122):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:175)
02-04 23:48:25.333: E/AndroidRuntime(2122):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToNext(AbstractCursor.java:243)
02-04 23:48:25.333: E/AndroidRuntime(2122):     at com.gam.sqlite.GamAppSqliteBDD.getAllDiscuss(GamAppSqliteBDD.java:242)
02-04 23:48:25.333: E/AndroidRuntime(2122):     at com.gam.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:116)
02-04 23:48:25.333: E/AndroidRuntime(2122):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
02-04 23:48:25.333: E/AndroidRuntime(2122):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
02-04 23:48:25.333: E/AndroidRuntime(2122):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
02-04 23:48:25.333: E/AndroidRuntime(2122):     ... 11 more
```

The line 242 of GamAppSqliteBDD.java file is :

```
} while (cursor.moveToNext());
```

Can anyone help me to understand and solve this error ?

I have this error too if I use the following code :

```
    public ArrayList<Discuss> getAllDiscuss(){
        ArrayList<Discuss> discussList = new ArrayList<Discuss>();
        Cursor cursor = bdd.query(TABLE_DISCUSS, new String[] {COL_DISCUSS_ID, COL_DISCUSS_ID_SERVER, COL_ID_OTHERUSER}, null, null, null, null, null);
        try {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
//                do {
                    discussList.add(cursorToDiscuss(cursor));
                    discussList.add(cursorToDiscuss(cursor));
//                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        } finally {
            try { cursor.close(); } catch (Exception ignore) {}
        }
        return discussList;
    }
```

But this time at the second line : `discussList.add(cursorToDiscuss(cursor));`

Thanks for your reading !

Comment: Post your `cursorToDiscuss()` code - likely you're closing the cursor there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[***Not Recommended***] I think the issue is closing the cursor. Just put that `cursor.close()` in comments and run again!!

```
//cursor.close()
```

[***Recommended***]

The error is at line

```
02-04 23:48:25.333: E/AndroidRuntime(2122): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery (mSql = SELECT ID, Id_Server, Id_OtherUser FROM Table_Discuss)
```

It says that you are trying to open object which is already closed. In this case its `cursor` you are using. You probably have cursor in operation even after you have closed it.

Getting your code in right order will play the trick ! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Thank you ! You help me to understand my error. I was passing my cursor in my method cursorToDiscuss() which is :

```
private Discuss cursorToDiscuss(Cursor c){
    if (c.getCount() == 0)
        return null;
    c.moveToFirst();
    Discuss discuss = new Discuss();
    discuss.setId(c.getInt(NUM_COL_DISCUSS_ID));
    discuss.setIdServer(c.getInt(NUM_COL_DISCUSS_ID_SERVER));
    discuss.setIdOtherUser(c.getInt(NUM_COL_ID_OTHERUSER));
    c.close();
    return discuss;
}
```

And in this method, I close the cursor before to return my object.

I have modified my method getAllDiscuss() in :

```
public ArrayList<Discuss> getAllDiscuss(){
    ArrayList<Discuss> discussList = new ArrayList<Discuss>();
    Cursor cursor = bdd.query(TABLE_DISCUSS, new String[] {COL_DISCUSS_ID, COL_DISCUSS_ID_SERVER, COL_ID_OTHERUSER}, null, null, null, null, null);
    try {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Discuss discuss = new Discuss();
                discuss.setId(cursor.getInt(NUM_COL_DISCUSS_ID));
                discuss.setIdServer(cursor.getInt(NUM_COL_DISCUSS_ID_SERVER));
                discuss.setIdOtherUser(cursor.getInt(NUM_COL_ID_OTHERUSER));
                discussList.add(discuss);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    } finally {
        try { cursor.close(); } catch (Exception ignore) {}
    }
    return discussList;
}
```

And it's finally working !

Thanks for your help :)